# Unable to get data from django choice form

Tags: django, django-forms

Hi, I'm trying to develop a simple django app, and I'm having trouble accessing a form's data. I've looked at django's documentation extensively and many questions on here on the same topic but nothing is working. Here's my code inside my view, that is otherwise working:

```
def post(self, request):
    """Return only the games from the upcoming gameweek"""
    form = GWForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        curr_gw = form.cleaned_data['gweek']
        args = {'form': form, 'this_gw_fixtures': Game.objects.filter(gweek=curr_gw), 'curr_gw': curr_gw}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)
    else:
        curr_gw = 17
        form = GWForm()
        args = {'form': form, 'this_gw_fixtures': Game.objects.filter(gweek=curr_gw), 'curr_gw': curr_gw}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

And here's the code of my template:

```
<form action="/predict/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <label for="Gameweek">Gameweek: </label>
    <input id="gwparam" type="number" value="{{ curr_gw }}" min="17" max="40">
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
    {% if this_gw_fixtures %}
        <ul>
        {% for game in this_gw_fixtures %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'predict:detail' game.id %}">{{ game }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>


    {% else %}
        <p>No game predictions are available for this gameweek.</p>
    {% endif %}
```

What I'm trying to do is get the input of a choice form and render a list of games that are in the gameweek selected in the form. Minumum 17, max 40. Here's my form code.

```
class GWForm(forms.Form):
    gweek = forms.ChoiceField(required = False, choices=[(x, x) for x in range(17, 40)])
```

But when I try to grab the gweek from the form, is_valid() returns true, but form.cleaned_data['gweek'] doesn't return any value at all. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

forms.py

```
class GWForm(forms.Form):
    gweek = forms.IntegerField(required=False, min_value=17, max_value=40)
```

template

```
<form action="/predict/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

Comment: It's working correctly now. tysm for the quick response